# Random numbers in function .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I wrote this:

```js
var x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 1)) + 1).toFixed(1);
 $("div[style='top: "x"px; opacity: 0.5;']").click();
```

I want to `x` in `top: "x"px` be random compartment from 0 to 1 with one place after the coma and text behind this will be like using it `*`, I mean any text behind this will be true.

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you explain more what you're trying to do?

Comment: Try using google translate, it seems like you want to calculate the value for top, using a random value, but I'm not sure about the rest... sorry

Comment: I try to make 0 random number for 0 to 1 with one place after the coma like this   ` $("div[style='top: 0.3px;' *]"` including 0 and 1

Comment: See if Math.random() and toFixed() will help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random and here is toFixed docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: Like in my edit post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues with your code.

1. `Math.random() * (1 - 1)` This is 0, and will always be 0 because you multiply a random number by a value `(1 - 1)` which is 0, any number times 0 is 0.
2. `"div[style='top: "x"px; opacity: 0.5;']"` That is not how you string concatenate. You need to concatenate the two strings with your `x` variable using the `+` operator:

   ```
   "div[style='top: " + x + "px; opacity: 0.5;']"
   ```